# emacs minimap: how to highlight functions using semantic/face

Tags: python, emacs, font-lock, emacs-ecb, emacs-faces

I am trying to customize the minimap package in emacs.

I'd like to be able to read the name of the functions, class, etc while in the minimap. The effect I am trying to achieve is this (although in python mode):  (from www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap)

[image: copied from "www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap"]

As far as I understand the minimap module, there are two way to enlarge the name of function, class, etc.

The first requires semantic overlays, but I am not familiar with the semantic package, and I am not sure how well it supports python.

The second (that I set as the default option from `M-x customize-group minimap`) should use the normal text height for all the functions - all the text with the face `font-lock-function-name-face` - but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to use this minimap function?

Comment: Open up the main `minimap.el` and search for the word `face` -- I see several that could be adjusted either within your init, or by hacking the source.  If you have an elc, then you will need to delete it after hacking the el and run a new `M-x byte-compile-file` if you opt for hacking the source instead of trying to adjust the variables solely through the init.